# Detect Polygons from Randomly Listed Edges

Tags: algorithm, geometry, 2d, computational-geometry

I have a vector drawing containing the edges of lots of polygons. Each edge is represented by a start point and end point. Connections between edges are not explicitly indicated. I need to extract the polygons from this data. The obvious way to do this is to take one vertex of each edge, search all other edges for a matching vertex and repeat this with the next vertex of the edge so located till I have a closed loop. But this is very inefficient.

What are some good algorithms out there to extract polygons given only start and end points of edges in no particular order?

Comment: Will your edges cross? What do you want to happen if they do?

Comment: @angelatlarge: That is rather important, as if that happens often, the worst case performance can get rather bad.

Comment: @angelatlarge @M C, the edges do not cross. They only meet at the ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this (python-pseudocode):

```
vertices = {} #map (x, y) coords to a list of all edges containing that vertex

for edge in edges:
    #add start & end vertices
    if edge.start not in vertices:
        vertices[edge.start] = []
    if edge.end not in vertices:
        vertices[edge.end] = []
    vertices[edge.start].append(edge)
    vertices[edge.end].append(edge)
```

Now you have all the vertices and all the edges coming out of each vertex. You can now do the initial idea for your algorithm, but instead of having to search through all the edges for a matching vertex, that lookup is instant.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do it would be:

```
Sort the list of edges by end point. Call that array edges
Create a new array, polygon, size is num_edges 
edgeIndex = 0
copy edge from edges[0] to polygon[0]
count = 1
while (count < number_of_edges)
{
    starting_point = edges[edgeIndex].endpoint
    // do a binary search to find the segment that starts
    // at this edge's end point
    newIndex = binary_search(edges, starting_point)
    copy edge[newIndex] to polygon[count]
    ++count
    edgeIndex = newIndex
}
```

When you're done with this, the `polygon` array should contain the edges, in order.

The above assumes that the edge points are output rationally. That is, given a triangle with vertices '[(0, 0), (10, 10), (10, 0)]', the edges are given as:

```
{(0, 0), (10, 10)}
{(10, 10), (10, 0)}
{(10, 0), (0, 0)}
```

Although not necessarily in that order. If the second edge is given as `{(10, 0), (10, 10)}` (i.e. start and end are reversed), then the problem is somewhat more difficult.

You can do the same thing with a hash map and direct lookups, which will be faster than binary search.

Note also that this assumes you won't have more than two edges connected to any single point.

Comment: there are multiple polygons involved.